# Bot framework v4.0 how to execute the previous waterfall step in a dialog

Tags: c#, botframework, waterfall

I'm trying to create a dialog in which I define multiple waterfall steps. In the context of this dialog, I need sometimes to go back to the previous waterfall step according to the choice of the user. I found this method :

```
 await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync("Name of the dialog");
```

however, this method re-execute the whole dialog and this is not what I need.

In fact, the waterfall steps that I created are three :

- ChoiceCallStepAsync: The first step will list the first 10 calls of the user with the options to show older steps
- ShowCallStepAsync: The second step will show the call that the user choose or go back to the first step if the user clicked on "show older"
- EndDialog: The third step will terminate the dialog

My code is :

```
public class ListAllCallsDialog : ComponentDialog
    {

        // Dialog IDs
        private const string ProfileDialog = "ListAllCallsDialog";



        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ListAllCallsDialog"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="loggerFactory">The <see cref="ILoggerFactory"/> that enables logging and tracing.</param>
        public ListAllCallsDialog(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            : base(nameof(ListAllCallsDialog))
        {
            // Add control flow dialogs
            var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                   ListAllCallsDialogSteps.ChoiceCallStepAsync,
                   ListAllCallsDialogSteps.ShowCallStepAsync,
                   ListAllCallsDialogSteps.EndDialog,
            };
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(ProfileDialog, waterfallSteps));
            AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt("cardPrompt"));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains the waterfall dialog steps for the main dialog.
        /// </summary>
        private static class ListAllCallsDialogSteps
        {
            static int callListDepth = 0;
            static List<string> Calls;
            public static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ChoiceCallStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
                   "Right now i'm in list all calls dialog",
                   cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                GetAllCalls();
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync("cardPrompt", GenerateOptions(stepContext.Context.Activity, callListDepth), cancellationToken);
            }

            public static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ShowCallStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                // Get the text from the activity to use to show the correct card
                var text = stepContext.Context.Activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant();
                if(text == "Show older")
                    //Go back to the first step
                else if(text == "Show earlier")
                    //Go back to the first step
                else
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
                   "The call you choose is : " + text.ToString(),
                   cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                   return await stepContext.ContinueDialogAsync();

            }

            public static async Task<DialogTurnResult> EndDialog(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
               "Getting back to the parent Dialog",
               cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Creates options for a <see cref="ChoicePrompt"/> so the user may select an option.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="activity">The message activity the bot received.</param>
            /// <returns>A <see cref="PromptOptions"/> to be used in a prompt.</returns>
            /// <remarks>Related type <see cref="Choice"/>.</remarks>
            private static PromptOptions GenerateOptions(Activity activity, int callListDepth)
            {
                // Create options for the prompt
                var options = new PromptOptions()
                {
                    Prompt = activity.CreateReply("Please choose a call from the list below"),
                    Choices = new List<Choice>(),
                };


                for(int i=10*callListDepth; i <= 10 * (callListDepth + 1); i++)
                {
                    if (Calls.ElementAtOrDefault(i) != null)
                      options.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = Calls[i] });

                }
                options.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = "Show older" });
                if(callListDepth!=0)
                    options.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = "Show earlier" });
                return options;
            }
            private static void GetAllCalls()
            {

                //List of all calls found
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                  Calls.Add("Call" + i.ToString());
            }

        }
```

}

Can someone show me how to do this, please ?

Comment: I'm actually having the same problem, if you came across a solution please share it with us

Comment: @ZiadAkiki read my answer below, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 20):

I'm not sure, if it's the right and efficient way to do it, but you can experiment with the `State` property of the `context.ActiveDialog` within your `Task<DialogTurnResult>` function.

```
context.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] = (int)context.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] -2;
```

Comment: This works. If ( need to go back) then 

stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] = (int)stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] - 2;

return await AskStep1Async(stepContext, cancellationToken);

Comment: @Oyen I'm just calling NextAsync or ContiniueDialogAsync as usual without any problems. -1 if I want to return to the same dialog that I'm currently in, and built in validation doesn't fit for some reason, and -2 if want to go back to the previous one.

Comment: Yes, I was showing support to your answr because they still did not mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 6):

Waterfall dialogs weren't designed with the idea of 'going backwards' to traverse them, though I can see the possible need to. The only solution I've found is to break your waterfall into smaller "mini" waterfalls, and nest them into one larger waterfall.

```
        // define and add waterfall dialogs (main)
        WaterfallStep[] welcomeDialogSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            MainDialogSteps.PresentMenuAsync,
            MainDialogSteps.ProcessInputAsync,
            MainDialogSteps.RepeatMenuAsync,
        };
```

Then in MainDialogSteps.ProcessInputAsync:

```
        public static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ProcessInputAsync(
            WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var choice = (FoundChoice)stepContext.Result;
            var dialogId = Lists.WelcomeOptions[choice.Index].DialogName;

            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(dialogId, null, cancellationToken);
        }
```

This allows the users to start new dialogs still within the main dialog stack. One of my options I offered was a prompt of a list of phone numbers:

```
        WaterfallStep[] phoneChoiceDialogSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            PhoneChoicePromptSteps.PromptForPhoneAsync,
            PhoneChoicePromptSteps.ConfirmPhoneAsync,
            PhoneChoicePromptSteps.ProcessInputAsync,
        };

        Add(new WaterfallDialog(Dialogs.PhonePrompt, phoneChoiceDialogSteps));
```

And finally, in the PhoneChoicePromptSteps.ProcessInputAsync, I allowed for the selection of 'no' from the confirm to ReplaceDialogAsync and effectivly reset this smaller waterfall, without effecting the rest of the overall waterfall:

```
 public static async Task<DialogTurnResult> ProcessInputAsync(
            WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if ((bool)stepContext.Result)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
                    $"Calling {stepContext.Values[Outputs.PhoneNumber]}",
                    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(Dialogs.PhonePrompt, null, cancellationToken);
            } 
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I understand. In a nutshell putting the waterfall step that is ought to be re-executed in the head of a mini smaller waterfall steps should do the trick. This way re-executing the this waterfall step is done by replacing the dialog that contains the mini waterfall steps by itself in the final waterfall step.

Comment: Exactly. That way, your user can then proceed along the dialog with the bot, and if further "You chose XYZ, confirm?" steps are needed, you can loop around that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the option parameter in the method "ReplaceDialogAsync" and skip steps with the method "NextAsync".

For example in my waterfall steps (defined in the constructor):

```
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            IntroStepAsync,
            ActStepAsync,
            FinalStepAsync
        }));

        // The initial child Dialog to run.
        InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
```

If you want pass to second step (in my case ActStepAsync) from the final step (FinalStepAsync) , when I going to replace the dialog I use the created a label in the Dialog:

```
private const string FLAG = "MY_FLAG";
```

When I invoke the method **from final step** I do this :

```
return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(InitialDialogId, FLAG, cancellationToken);
```

So I only need check the option **in the first step** if the context has the flag :

```
    // Use the text provided in FinalStepAsync or the default if it is the first time.
        var messageText = stepContext.Options?.ToString() ?? "welcome-message";
        if (messageText.Equals(FLAG_REPROMPT))
        {
            return await stepContext.NextAsync(null,cancellationToken);
        }
```

Later this **you are in the second step**