# About waterfall steps in azure bot

Tags: c#, botframework

How do I repeat waterfall steps in Azure Botframework? I want to ask some prompts, and repeat a prompt if needed. How do I repeat steps or start the waterfall from the age prompt?

```
 var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
                InitializeStateStepAsync,
                PromptForNameStepAsync,
                PromptForAgeStepAsync,
                DisplayGreetingStateStepAsync,
                PromptForColorStepAsync,
                PromptForTypeStepAsync,
                ShoppingstepAsync,
                firststepAsync,
                secondstepAsync,
        };
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(ProfileDialog, waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(NamePrompt, ValidateName));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(AgePrompt, ValidateAge));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(ColorPrompt, ValidateColor));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(type_ofPrompt, ValidateType));
       AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(Choice));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bot framework v4.0 how to execute the previous waterfall step in a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554441/bot-framework-v4-0-how-to-execute-the-previous-waterfall-step-in-a-dialog)

Comment: when i use ReplaceDialogAsync it is not waiting for the user in first prompt its waiting from second prompt

Comment: In order to repeat steps, you need to break this waterfall into a series of mini waterfalls, all nested into one.