# Use NumberPrompt for multiple questions requiring user input C#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, botframework

I have multiple questions to ask users which are fetched from the DB. If I use `for` loop, all the questions are fired at once, not allowing the user to input their answer. However, using the keyword `return` allows the users to input their answer. I'm not sure how to use `NumberPrompt` for multiple questions requiring user input.

I'm planning to execute the code below in a `for` loop, but the `for` loop doesn't wait for the user input, and using the `return` keyword breaks the `for` loop.

```cs
var showQuestionMessageText = $"Here's your question: {ConnectDatabase.question[i]}";

var showQuestionMessage = MessageFactory.Text(showQuestionMessageText, showQuestionMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(showQuestionMessage, cancellationToken);

var showOptionsMessageText = $"Here's your options: \n1. {ConnectDatabase.option1[i]} \n2. {ConnectDatabase.option2[i]} \n3. {ConnectDatabase.option3[i]} \n4. {ConnectDatabase.option4[i]}";
var showOptionsMessage = MessageFactory.Text(showOptionsMessageText, showOptionsMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(showOptionsMessage, cancellationToken);

return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(NumberPrompt<int>), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please choose one of the options, using 1-4 to type in your answer")}, cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "Waterfall dialogs" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-waterfall-dialogs?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#waterfall-dialogs

> At each step, the bot prompts the user for input (or can begin a child dialog, but that it's often a prompt), waits for a response, and then passes the result to the next step.

Waterfall dialog will go back to "TurnContext" everytime when user finish a prompt. Try this "multi-turn-prompt" sample:  https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/Dialogs/UserProfileDialog.cs

Comment: hi there, thanks for your response. I'm using waterfall dialog with my code. I had a look at the code in the link, but it doesn't seem to involve multiple questions in one method.

Comment: @Coder2656 I think it should be multiple questions in multiple `Task<DialogTurnResult>` method as the sample.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Could you please clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @Coder2656 I mean if you check this sample, it is asking multiple questions, right? And each question has a `stepContext.PromptAsync` in the `Task<DialogTurnResult>` method.

Comment: @Coder2656 And you need to save the question number "i" to userState for nextstep using.

Comment: Yeah, it is using multiple questions, but not in a for loop like I would prefer. Do you mean to say that I should create seperate methods for the different questions?

Comment: @Coder2656 Yes. I think you need a "return" or the bot won't waiting for user input. Maybe you could repeat a step of a dialog like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61776567/20240963

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the return being required. I'll have a look into the link, thanks a lot.